# source code differs from inspect element code by changing tags positions

Tags: php, html

When my page is loaded from the server, source code differs from inspect element by changing the tags positions.
Here how the code looks in the view-source page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainclasses.css">
        <title>title  </title>
    </head>
<body style="margin:0px;">
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:0px auto;">
```

but when I inspect elements all the tags inside the `head` tag goes under the body tag, and two double quotations appear under the `body` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head></head>
<body style="margin:0px;">
""
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainclasses.css">
<title>title  </title>
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:0px auto;">
```

The page works perfectly and all css properties appears and the title also appears.But I also want the HTML code to be good.

I searched for this and found many things that may cause this problem and none of them helped me.

- There is no JavaScript code in my website, and I disabled all browser extensions so that JavaScript don't affect the page.I also checked the source tab in the developer tool and no JavaScript code were there.
- I checked all my css properties and none of them causes this problem.(css also doesn't put strange chars).
- The quotations that appeared are not spaces. I tried to put all my php code in one line and remove all unnecessary spaces and it didn't work.
- I'm not using `UTF8 BOM` encoding, all files are `UTF8 without BOM`.so the strange chars are not due to file encoding.
- I'm sure that the php files print the tags in the right order and don't print any quotation mark.
- When I right-click the quotation marks in the developer tool,I only have the option `Break on`, and I can't edit it as HTML.
- I tried to run the page from other web browsers and the problem didn't go.
- I'm not using any framework.

What would be the cause of this problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: You've said you've used php. Could you provide that markup?

Comment: @jbutler483 It's very hard to put my php code since I use more than 4 PHP pages to construct the HTML page.

Comment: What do you mean by "inspect the elements"?  What tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using google chrome. When I right-click the quotations or any element and choose `inspect element` from the menu,it leads me to the `elements` bar in chrome developer tool. It's the same when you press F12

Comment: try validating your markup here https://validator.w3.org

Comment: The most likely culprit is indeed wrong markup. Triple check it.

Comment: @B-and-P Looks like there's a problem with the website right now `503 Service Unavailable. No server is available to handle this request.` But I'll try later. Thanks

Comment: When you use "inspect", you see the DOM tree as browser sees it. It may be different from the actual source if the original markup is wrong. It may help to identify the broken markup by using "view source" function - modern browsers highlight it and this can give you a clue. Probably you have wrong quote or mistype somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I checked my HTML code. there were a symbol somewhere inside the `head` tag.  I deleted the symbol and the HTML code in developer tool was corrected.